# How to store Listeners for multiple Event types

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement Observer/Listener pattern with multiple listeners and multiple event types in Java. Each event listener can be interested in one or more event types.

What is the most efficient way to store listeners for each particular event type and iterate over them (List of Lists, maybe)?

Of course, thread-safe solution is strongly preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for Thread safe hash map.

The structure you need is:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<EventType,List<Listener>> map;
```

That way, each listener is registered to several event types.

Comment: That will require going through every listener when a specific event happens, which does not strike me as very efficient.

Comment: So list of lists is the only real option?

Comment: @jerome is right, I meant it to be the other way around, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) class? But I may have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html). It holds a list of anything implementing [EventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html). Then you can call `getListeners(class)` to get the listeners of type `class`.

Comment: AFAIK EventListenerList requires iterating over array of all registered Listeners and determining if each of them is interested in particular type of event.

Comment: [getListeners(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html#getListeners(java.lang.Class))

Comment: Yes, it does. The `getListeners(clazz)` call returns all objects implementing or extending `clazz`. Then you iterate over that. In practice it is rare for the list to exceed more than a handful of entries.  If you have a case where you have a significantly higher number, a redesign may be in order.

Comment: Looking at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.java#134), the class is a flat list and it filters the entries for you. If this winds up being your bottleneck, you will need to pre-split the entries, perhaps like @ftom2 has suggested